# calculating prime numbers using only odd numbers takes longer than odd and even

Tags: c#, iteration

I was working on a [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net) challenge and solved it. Then a friend suggested that I only compare potential prime numbers to known primes. His solution is done in about half the time.

I went back and made a new method to only calculate odd numbers as potential primes (i+=2), but it takes longer than doing i++. (I ran in Release Mode) Can anyone explain why?

Here's a [link](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=BB5EE09D5940EE13!168307&authkey=!ADKi36jrC91KXpk&ithint=folder%2csln) to the c# console app.

Here are the results:

[image]

Here's the code:

```
public class Program
{
    private static int PrimeNumbersCount = 0;
    private static int PrimeNumber = 10001;
    private static List<int> Primes ; 

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Reset();

        DoIt(MichaelsWay);
        DoIt(NelsonsWay);
        DoIt(OurWay);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void DoIt(Func<int> WhosWay)
    {
        DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
        int i = WhosWay();
        Console.WriteLine(i);
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now - start);
        Reset();
    }

    private static void Reset()
    {
        PrimeNumbersCount = 0;
        InitializePrimes();
    }

    private static void InitializePrimes()
    {
        Primes = new List<int>(new[] {2});
    }

    private static int OurWay()
    {
        // factor in 2 already being done
        PrimeNumbersCount++;
        // end factor in 2

        bool isPrime = true;
        int i;
        int operationsdone = 0;

        for (i = 3; PrimeNumbersCount < PrimeNumber; i+=2)
        {
            if (Primes.Any(j => i % j == 0))
            {
                isPrime = false;
                operationsdone++;
            }

            if (isPrime)
            {
                PrimeNumbersCount++;
                Primes.Add(i);
            }

            isPrime = true;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Our way operations done: " + operationsdone);
        return i - 2;
    }

    private static int NelsonsWay()
    {
        bool isPrime = true;
        int i;
        int operationsdone = 0;

        PrimeNumbersCount++; //to account for starting the loop at 2

        for (i = 2; PrimeNumbersCount < PrimeNumber; i++)
        {
            if (Primes.Any(j => i%j == 0))
            {
                isPrime = false;
                operationsdone++;
            }

            if (isPrime)
            {
                PrimeNumbersCount++;
                Primes.Add(i);
            }

            isPrime = true;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Nelson's way operations done: " + operationsdone);
        return i - 1;
    }

    private static int MichaelsWay()
    {
        bool isPrime = true;
        int i;
        int operationsdone = 0;
        int tempPrimeNumber = PrimeNumber + 1;

        for (i = 1; PrimeNumbersCount < tempPrimeNumber; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 2; j < i - 1; j++)
            {
                if (i%j == 0)
                {
                    isPrime = false;
                    operationsdone++;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (isPrime)
                PrimeNumbersCount++;

            isPrime = true;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Michael's way operations done: " + operationsdone);
        return i - 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is working code and would be better suited on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: I didn't even know about that. Thanks!

Comment: @HansPassant actually, I am Mike, and I wrote all of it XD Nelson is a friend who is getting ready to start his CS work in university (woo-hoo! converted him!). I actually used .Any in Nelson's way because Resharper suggested it and I kind of assumed that .Any would break if the condition was met on any of the numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I'll take a guess:

You only call Reset(), clearing the list `Primes`, at the beginning.

You are performing `NelsonsWay` first, which populates a list.
You then perform `OurWay`, which appends items to the same list.

Understand that `List<T>` stores all of its items in one contiguous array. If you've filled this array, and then try to add another item, the List must allocate a new, bigger, block of space and copy all of the existing items to this new memory space. The length of time this allocation takes will be proportional to the list's current size.

Hence, if you are continually adding items to the same list, performance will deteriorate as the size increases.

Remove the line `Primes.Add(...)` from both `NelsonsWay` and `OurWay`, and you will see that `OurWay` does indeed run faster.

Comment: I believe that the list is getting re-initialized in the reset method that is called at the end of every "DoIt," so it is getting cleared, right? or am I missing something

Comment: @Michael DiLeo - No, it was me who overlooked that line of code. All the same, adding something to the list will involve dynamic memory allocation, and in the Garbage-Collection-Enabled .NET environment, memory allocation behaves in a non-deterministic way. So try removing the call to Primes.Add(...) and see if you still have the unexpected performance results.

Answer (score 0):

In alu, increasing command (i++), takes one clock pulse, but when you use summation function it takes two CP (in older systems it may takes three CP)

Comment: Ah, I thought that that might have something to do with it, but I didn't think it would matter too much, since I'm doing a lot more than that when I actually check for primes.